# Any security risk of reading/writing to a shared spreadsheet where anyone with link can edit? Project is in another SS

Tags: google-apps-script

The setup is such where one Spreadsheet (lets call it SS_PUBLIC) is shared with the option that anyone with link can edit. The people with which this link is shared with will be informed they should keep the link private as much as a password. This spreadsheet will be used to allow those people to enter data and will also have data written to it from a script in another spreadsheet (SS_PRIVATE).

This other spreadsheet (SS_PRIVATE) will contain my scripts as well as credentials to a database and should in no way be accessible from SS_PUBLIC. I confirmed that its possible for SS_PRIVATE to read from/write to SS_PUBLIC, and I really can't see how SS_PUBLIC could access the code from SS_PRIVATE, but I want to see what others though.

**EDIT:** The way I am reading from / writing to SS_PUBLIC is via the simplified code below which is stored in the SS_PRIVATE project:

```js
function readWriteTest() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SS_PUBLIC_ID_HERE');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    Logger.log(sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue()); // read val from public ss
    sheet.getRange(2, 1).setValue("write this"); // write val to public ss
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you copy the data from the private spreadsheet to the public one? By copypaste? Then you should be fine, as long as you do not grant access to the private spreadsheet to anyone, no one other than you would have access.

But, still, if functions like [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) are used to retrieve data from a private spreadsheets, by using it, you are granting permission access to the spreadsheet from where you are importing the data.
So, anyone with edit access on that spreadsheet could retrieve any data from the private spreadsheet you granted access to at the first moment. So if you use it, you should be very careful with it.

Anyway if you are not using it, do not believe that what you are using is a good security standard at all:

If a public spreadsheet has any data that not everyone should have access to then it should not be public, secure it. You should grant access only to the people you wish to.

Comment: Added your requested details to my question. I am using the google apps scripts `sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue()` and `sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue()` functions if that makes any difference. I understand its not good security practice, but my question also extends to cases where the sheet is per-email restricted (can those users see the private data).

Comment: No, if you are filling the public spreadsheed through apps scripts then it is secure, you'll only risk the data that you have inserted on the public spreadsheet

Comment: Interesting, I wonder how this works with ownership... can you use app scripts to write to spreadsheets that you aren't the owner of but have edit permissions to?

Comment: Yep, sure you can. Please, if you feel the question is been solved mark it as such.